# NERDTree open in a new tab, as last tab in gvim?

Tags: vim

In NERDTree <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> opens file in a new tab, but tab is positioned after the tab in which NERDTree is opened.

It is possible to open the new tab at the end of tabs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/nerdtree.vim` with the following contents, then you will not have to edit NERDTree itself:

```
if exists('b:haveRemappedT')
    finish
endif
let b:haveRemappedT=1
let s:oldmap=maparg('T', 'n')
function! s:LastTab()
    let tab=tabpagenr()
    tabnext
    execute "tabmove ".tabpagenr('$')
    execute "tabn ".tab
endfunction
execute 'nnoremap <buffer> T '.s:oldmap.':call <SID>LastTab()<CR>'
```

Comment: @Zyx it is not working for me. I still get the opened file in a a new tab on the left when I pres shift + T. This is what I have: http://pastebin.com/kri7Byvb

Answer (score 6):

Here's a general purpose autocmd for opening all new tabs at the end. It works with NERDTree too.

```
" move tabs to the end for new, single buffers (exclude splits)
autocmd BufNew * if winnr('$') == 1 | tabmove99 | endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your .vimrc

```
autocmd BufNew * execute ":tabmove99"
```

This will always position newly open tabs at location 99 to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you edit the plugin and remap it to `:tablast` before `:tabnew`.

Comment: Isn't possible to overwrite mappings in `.vimrc`?

Comment: I am not sure in what order scripts will be read. `:scriptnames` will tell you. If `.vimrc` comes after NERDTree, you can remap it inside your .vimrc of course :)

Comment: Good to know about `:scriptnames` :) Thanks

Comment: Or you can create ~/.vim/after/plugin/NERD_tree.vim as it will be read after the plugin. BTW thanks for :scriptnames :)